# Resizing Rotated Rectangle with OriginX and OriginY values

Tags: flutter, canvas, graphics, geometry, fabricjs

I am developing a Canvas library in FLutter/Dart, like FabricJS but for much simpler tasks. When I get the project to a certain stage, I will share it on pub.dev and Github.

I've been struggling with this problem for a few days, please help.

Basically every drawing object is a class. Each object simply has values Left, Top, Width, Height, ScaleX, ScaleY, Angle (degree of ration), OriginX and OriginY.

OriginX and OriginY is an Enum and contains the following.

enum OriginX { left, right, center }
enum OriginY { top, bottom, center }

If you set the OriginX of an object to "left", the object will be drawn from the left side from the 100th pixel. If you give the value "right", the object will draw itself from the right side at the 100th pixel.

I draw a small box at the 4 corners of the objects and in the middle of the left and right side. I use these to change the size of the object. But I don't change the size of the objects by changing their Width and Height, but by changing their ScaleX and ScaleY values. So I am scaling.

I wrote an ActionHandler method for the scaling objects in the corner. My main problem is that if the object is rotated, the object moves to different positions in a meaningless way when changing the scale of the object. The reason for this is the problem caused by the rotation applied to the object. For example, if the object is 0 degrees, when I hold the object by the right center handle and enlarge it, it grows smoothly and the width grows following the current position of the mouse. If I grab the object by the left center handle and pull it, no problem.

If the Angle value of the object is 0 and regardless of the OriginX, OriginY value, I can grab it at any point and scale it.

But for example, if OriginX = left and you have given the object a 45 degree tilt and you hold it at the right center scaling point, it will grow smoothly. Because you scaled by holding it from the right side and the object always keeps itself fixed to OriginX.left. But on the contrary, if it is from the left side and the scaling is OriginX.left, the position of the object is distorted. it should be fixed from the right side and scaled 45 degrees upwards.

Changing the Left and Top values of the object directly means that the object takes into account the OriginX and OriginY values of the object and makes the drawing points of the object in the background according to these Origin values.

In addition, I am doing the ScaleX and ScaleY calculations correctly, but when the degree of rotation is involved, the scale of the object does not exactly coincide with the points I hold with the mouse.

I need to assign the results of the whole calculation to the object's Left, Top, ScaleX and ScaleY properties. Because everything is rendered according to the object's values.

I made a short video, please watch the video from the link below.

https://streamable.com/sco5de

I also read the article here and it solves the same problem I have. But I could not apply it to my system.

https://shihn.ca/posts/2020/resizing-rotated-elements/

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLc8f.png)

**Scale Handler Codes**

```
  void onActionHandler(dynamic details, GestureType gestureType,
      BasicObject object, ObjectControl control) {
    if (gestureType == GestureType.onPanDown) {
      final point = (details as DragDownDetails).localPosition;
      properties.set('firstPoint', point);
    } else if (gestureType == GestureType.onPanUpdate) {
      final lastPoint = (details as DragUpdateDetails).localPosition;

      //This assigns the value of LastPoint to
      // "firstPoint", overwrites it and returns the value of "firstPoint" before overwriting.
      //The properties variable is used for general purpose value storage.
      Offset delta =
          lastPoint - properties.swap<Offset>('firstPoint', lastPoint);


      //These variables indicate if the object is scaled in the right or
      // down direction. If this is not done and you grab the object's left
      // center scaling control and pull it to the left, the object will shrink
      // instead of grow. So the opposite will happen and we prevent this.

      bool positiveHorizontalScale = true;
      bool positiveVerticalScale = true;

      //The "option" variable returns the enum value
      // of whichever checkpoint it is held from.
      final option = getControlOption(control)!;

      if (option == ControlsOptions.tl) {
        positiveHorizontalScale = false;
        positiveVerticalScale = false;
      } else if (option == ControlsOptions.mt || option == ControlsOptions.tr) {
        positiveVerticalScale = false;
      } else if (option == ControlsOptions.bl || option == ControlsOptions.ml) {
        positiveHorizontalScale = false;
      }

      if (!positiveHorizontalScale) {
        delta = Offset(-delta.dx, delta.dy);
      }
      if (!positiveVerticalScale) {
        delta = Offset(delta.dx, -delta.dy);
      }

      //These variables specify whether the object is scaled in both directions
      // or in a particular direction.
      bool adjustHorizontal = false;
      bool adjustVertical = false;

      final scaledWidth = width * scaleX;
      final scaledHeight = height * scaleY;

      //Calculate ScaleX and ScaleY values required for scaling.
      final sX = (scaledWidth + delta.dx) / scaledWidth * scaleX;
      final sY = (scaledHeight + delta.dy) / scaledHeight * scaleY;

      double tempScaleX = scaleX;
      double tempScaleY = scaleY;
      double tempLeft = left;
      double tempTop = top;

      switch (option) {
        case ControlsOptions.tl:
        case ControlsOptions.tr:
        case ControlsOptions.bl:
        case ControlsOptions.br:
          {
            tempScaleX = sX;
            tempScaleY = sY;
            adjustHorizontal = true;
            adjustVertical = true;
          }
          break;
        case ControlsOptions.ml:
        case ControlsOptions.mr:
          {
            tempScaleX = sX;
            adjustHorizontal = true;
          }
          break;
        case ControlsOptions.mt:
        case ControlsOptions.mb:
          {
            tempScaleY = sY;
            adjustVertical = true;
          }
          break;
        case ControlsOptions.mtr:
          {}
          break;
      }

      //If scaling in horizontal direction
      if (adjustHorizontal) {
        if (originX == OriginX.right && positiveHorizontalScale) {
          tempLeft = tempLeft + delta.dx;
        }
        if (originX == OriginX.center) {
          if (positiveHorizontalScale) {
            tempLeft = tempLeft + delta.dx / 2;
          } else {
            tempLeft = tempLeft - delta.dx / 2;
          }
        }
        if (originX == OriginX.left && !positiveHorizontalScale) {
          tempLeft = tempLeft - delta.dx;
        }
      }

      //If scaling in vertical direction
      if (adjustVertical) {
        if (originY == OriginY.bottom && positiveVerticalScale) {
          tempTop = tempTop + delta.dy;
        }
        if (originY == OriginY.center) {
          if (positiveVerticalScale) {
            tempTop = tempTop + delta.dy / 2;
          } else {
            tempTop = tempTop - delta.dy / 2;
          }
        }
        if (originY == OriginY.top && !positiveVerticalScale) {
          tempTop = tempTop - delta.dy;
        }
      }

      left = tempLeft;
      top = tempTop;
      scaleX = tempScaleX;
      scaleY = tempScaleY;
      _controller!.render();
    }
  }
```

I developed methods for different calculations many times. I tried to solve my problem in ChatGPT.But I could not get the correct calculation in any way, there were always meaningless values.

Comment: see https://gist.github.com/pskink/a8a497c11365e65dda48648ac07e302b#file-flow_resizer-dart and it's minimal version https://gist.github.com/pskink/a8a497c11365e65dda48648ac07e302b#file-flow_resizer_minimal-dart

Comment: and if it is still unclear the whole trick is made in `_resize()` method

Comment: @pskink I will look into it in detail, thank you.

Comment: note that you don't have to use one `Flow` widget as i did - you can also have a `Stack` with multiple `Transform` children

Comment: @pskink I wrote a few short and explanatory things in the answer section, do you have a chance to look at it?

Comment: I don't know why you need that `Canvas.transform` at all, simply use `CustomPaint` as a child the same way I use two plain `Contsiner`s

Comment: @pskink The idea is to draw different objects on the Canvas. Not just a Rectangle. I am not interested in drawing or rotating any flutter widget. Canvas.save() method is running before Canvas.transform so that the current drawn object is transformed.
I understand exactly what you mean, but you want me to use CustomPaint as a widget through your library. Maybe I can use this. But I need to solve this problem to improve myself.
Can you tell me what is causing my problem?

Comment: I also need to save these rendered images as images later. I don't know if I can do this in your widget based system.

Comment: of course you can: simply make `RepaintBoundary` as a parent

Comment: @pskink I appreciate your example. I learned a lot from your code, but I am not able to use Widget Resizer. Because the requirements are very different. The simplest thing is to have a border around the selected object. Objects should support SkewX and SkewY properties, also events like OnScaling, OnMoving, OnMoved, LockMovementX, LockMovementY. LockSkewX, LockSkewY. If you turn this project into a library, I will be supporting you.

Comment: @pskink Also the built-in widgets don't exactly work properly. for example,

    ResizerFrameEntry(
        id: 2,
        angle: 0,
        rect: Offset.zero & const Size(200, 200),
        initialAlignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Image(
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
            image: NetworkImage(
                'https://docs.flutter.dev/assets/images/dash/dash-fainting.gif')))),

Comment: @pskink And I solved part of the problem. I wrote a function that converts Direct Point to a certain degree. but as I said, it does not follow the position of the mouse and does not work properly at 90 degrees.

Comment: @pskink Thank you. I reviewed the code.
You are using two different canvas. Widgets are CustomPaint. and you have a ContentPainter class. ContentPainter class draws by calling the paint method of ResizerFrameEntry's painter. When we turn it into a comment line in ContentPainter, yes there is no drawing and this made me realize something. The widget could still have rotation! I then commented out the transform calculation of the entry in the _resize() function and the object could still rotate because the transform matrix is meant to apply the matrix directly to the painter classes. ++

Comment: @pskink  There is also one more thing that I realized later. The actual place that does the rotation of the widget is paintChildren! I will think about it. I also experimented with SkewX and the resizin process is quite broken.

Comment: Let me ask you a quick question, imagine that the object is at 0 degrees and you magnify it to the right on the horizontal axis. you use the difference of the dx value of the last and first Offsets to calculate the growth Delta. For the horizontal plane! What happens if you make the object 90 degrees? The horizontal plane has hit the vertical plane. So we will have a problem calculating the difference of dx. because you are moving the mouse mostly on the vertical axis. So the dx delta can always be close to zero. +++

Comment: @pskink What is the solution in this case? Shouldn't we rotate the first and last Offset information? but you didn't do that, even though you used Matrix you need the dx difference for growth on the horizontal axis. because you use delta.dx in EdgeInsets! and when it is 90 degrees the mouse almost doesn't move on the horizontal plane. Please explain this to me, I need ideas please!

Comment: just `print(d.delta)` inside `_resize` method, first when angle is 0 deg and then after rotating by 90 deg, it will explain much

Comment: @pskink I'm really going crazy. I printed the values with print. In your project, I first set the angle value to 0 and printed the delta with print in the _resize function. The id value of the handle is 2, that is, the handle on the right side. When it was 0 degrees, the delta dx value was always much larger than 0 and the dy value was almost zero. I set the object to pi / 2, that is, 90 degrees. In this case the handle on the right side with id value 2 came down. and when I look at the delta values, the dx value is always greater than 0! how is this possible? ++

Comment: who updates the delta? and this delta value is a value belonging to DragUpdateDetails.

Comment: @pskink So when we draw the object with paintChild, the delta is updated according to the Angle value we give? That's great! But I use a single CustomPaint and each of my drawing objects has its own Angle value. When I get the delta value, I don't get it directly from DragUpdateDetails. In the PanDown event, I create a firstPoint value. In the PanUpdate event, I get the difference with lastPoint. How can I update the Delta value according to a certain angle? If I solve this Delta event, the whole problem will be solved!

Comment: it is already solved by using `Flow` widget, why do you want to do it by yourself and make your life harder? why not to use `Flow` widget instead?

Comment: How I will use it? My every object has different Angle, when I selected my object just I need selected object Angle. And my CustomPaint can't have Angle, because I use Angle for drawing objects, like rectangle or image or any shape. Because I don't use Widget for transform. that's why I am asking.

Comment: @pskink I'm talking about my own project. If I put my CustomPaint class as a child in Flow, can I get the Delta value as Rotated? Or how do I update the Delta value according to an Angle. Because I solved all other problems. Can you share the code snippet about updating the Delta value for Angle?

Comment: i don't have code for updating the delta, the `Flow` widget do that automatically

Comment: @pskink Does it update according to the Angle value of the active (focused) child in the Flow widget?

Comment: it updates based on `transform` parameter passed to `paintChild` method (for every child)

Comment: @pskink I solved this problem successfully. I left the codes in the answer section. Thank you for everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved all the problems! My thanks to @pskink who provided valuable information on the solution. Below you can see a full example of the working code.

```
  Offset rotateOffset(Offset offset, Offset centerPoint, double degree) {
    final radian = degree2Radian(degree);
    final o = offset - centerPoint;
    final x = o.dx * math.cos(radian) - o.dy * math.sin(radian);
    final y = o.dx * math.sin(radian) + o.dy * math.cos(radian);
    return Offset(x + centerPoint.dx, y + centerPoint.dy);
  }

delta = rotateOffset(delta, Offset.zero, -angle);
final r0 = getRect();
final i = getControlOptionIndex(option)!;
final insets = EdgeInsets.only(
    left: pads[i].left * -delta.dx,
    top: pads[i].top * -delta.dy,
    right: pads[i].right * delta.dx,
    bottom: pads[i].bottom * delta.dy);

final r1 = insets.inflateRect(r0);
final point = rotateOffset(r1.topLeft, r0.topLeft, angle);

left = point.dx;
top = point.dy;
width = r1.width;
height = r1.height;
```

Comment: `Offset rotateOffset(Offset offset, Offset centerPoint, double degree) {
final o = offset - centerPoint;
return centerPoint + Offset.fromDirection(o.direction + degree2Radian(degree), o.distance);
}` - still have no idea why you want to do that by hand when flutter can do that for you...

Comment: btw since you already have a `Matrix` used for `Canvas.transform` method the easiest way to get rotated offset is to use that matrix - most likely `MatrixUtils.transformPoint` will be enough (with the exact or maybe little modified `Matrix`)

Comment: @pskink quick question, how can we do a reverse resize using this structure, i.e. how can we resize backwards without the width and height having negative values, for example when grabbing from the right side and passing the starting point of the left side? Do you have a chance to make an example of this on your own code? Abs() doesn't work directly here because delta enlarges step by step.

Comment: most likely if Rect.right < Rect.left you could swap those two values and it should work

Comment: thanks but it didn't work. When I do what you said, the size of the object always remains at zero. and the object starts to shift completely to the left. 

        Rect r1 = insets.inflateRect(r0);
        if (r1.right < r1.left) {
          //r1 = Rect.fromLTWH(r1.right, r1.top, r1.width.abs(), r1.height.abs());
          r1 = Rect.fromLTRB(r1.right, r1.top, r1.left, r1.bottom);
        }

Comment: this is because you should have the reacts: input rect where right can be < left and output rect where right is always > left and any painting is made based on that output rect

Comment: @pskink Honestly, I don't fully understand. Are you talking about the r0 Rect variable? Do you have a chance to explain it more clearly? Or an example.

Comment: @pskink I mean, I guess it is not possible to do this reverse resize operation with EdgeInsets and Delta? I understand what you mean above. Normally, when you do a reverse resize, the input value returned from the getRect() function is already as you mentioned, that is, Rect < Left, but the output value is always negative. that is, the width value of the r1 variable is always negative. I tried many formulas but I couldn't do it.

Comment: I mean that if you have two rects: the first (input one) which can have any relation between left and right (so it can be left < right.most of time but sometimes it could be left > right) and the second which is based on the first but it's left is always < right and you use only the second rect for drawing